# Remove single quotes from an array using Java script / Node JS

Tags: arrays, node.js, javascript-objects, single-quotes

I am having an issue of single quotes around the array value.
I have an array which I have define as:

```
var latLongArray=[];
```

and the value I am getting is as below:

```
['{latitude:43.73747, longitude:7.163546}',
  '{latitude:50.127339, longitude:8.60512}',
  '{latitude:30.267, longitude:-97.743}' ]
```

I don't want single quotes, I tried using above all solution but not working for my issue.
I tried using below solutions to remove single quotes:

```
var newLatLongArray = latLongArray.join(',').replace(/'([^']+(?='))'/g, '$1'); 
// Remove single quotes
```

I am able to remove the single quotes but the newLatLongArray I am getting as a String but actually I want an array.

Any suggestion to get the value as an array with removing single quotes, please.

Comment: Just fill your array with objects not strings.

Answer (score 0):

At your line `var newLatLongArray = latLongArray.join(',').replace(/'([^']+(?='))'/g, '$1');`, you tell to join your array, replace the single quotes but you never split again.

The join() function will transform your array to a string, the replace will replace the wanted characters and give a string so you just need to add a .split(',') at the end like this:

```
var newLatLongArray = latLongArray.join(',').replace(/'([^']+(?='))'/g, '$1').split(',');
```

Hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll go under the assumption you want an array of lat/long objects.

In that case, you could use:

```
var data = latLongArray.map(item => {
    item = item.replace('latitude', '"latitude"').replace('longitude', '"longitude"');
    return JSON.parse(item);
}));
```